# Kernel dies while opening a pickle file Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am trying to open a pickle file with the code:

```
file_name = pd.read_pickle(r"path")
```

But the following error occurs: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

I don't know why it's happening, yesterday it worked well. The file is 323.000 KB but I opened other csv file bigger than the pickle one and it worked.

Comment: there is a typo, its `read_pickle`

Comment: typo in your ```read_piclke``` it should be ```read_pickle```

Comment: pd.read_pickle(r"path", engine='python')  got "read_pickle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine' "

Comment: Don't use Jupyter notebook. Use a simple .py script. I know a known problem with notebook. It has problems deallocate resources once the session is over which creates problems.

Comment: or upgrade jupyter notebook version